# Getting an empty array from Firestore although it is not nil

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a `String array` I have inside a document in my `Firestore Database`.
I added (Manually) one item to this array, but when I'm trying to get the items in that array, I always get an empty array instead.

This is my code so far:

```
func getUserFollowingList(id userId: String, completion: @escaping(Array<String>)->()) {
    let followingArray = [String]()
    db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(userId).getDocument { (doc, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            completion(followingArray)
        }

        guard let following = doc?.get(USER_FOLLOWING) else { return }
        let followingList = following as! [String]

        completion(followingList)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the firends list of the current user.

This is my Firestore database:

```
following
   0 "9RtM0wgiKee6I5Lo8EugTFihyXE3"
profile_image: "IMAGE_URL"
useremail: "user@test.com"
username: "Testuser"
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: What's the value of `USER_FOLLOWING`? Have you tried to hardocde that value?

Comment: @AlexMamo this is just "following" string I have inside a Constants.swift file, for convince.